# How to dynamically attach javascript to ahref?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, wordpress

I have the following link, which I need to use in a Wordpress/OptimizePress based site.

```
<a href="" onclick="document.MyForm.submit();return false;">Click Me</a>
```

The problem is that the OptimizePress LiveEditor will strip out the javascript.  So you are left with this:

```
<a>Click Me</a>
```

I'd like to attach the above javascript after the page has loaded.  I have three such links (forms) on this page.  Each will have the same javascript.  I was thinking maybe provide unique IDs for each but I'm not sure what is the best way to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get onClick attribute value on Dom ready & store it into any global var.

```
var clickAttr;

$(document).ready(function(){
     clickAttr = $('form a').attr('onClick');
});
```

After that on Window load you can add attribute onClick

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('form a').attr('onClick',clickAttr);
});
```

I am not sure that your requirement is satisfy with this code or not, but you can try this.

**Note: I am writing for A tag which is inside form without id or class, you can add a class or id to A tag.**

Comment: The replacement works fine.  But this prevents the link from doing anything: javascript:void(0).  How do I get href=""?

Answer (score 0):

Try after load:

```
var $a = $('<a href="" onclick="document.MyForm.submit();return false;">Click Me</a>')
$( "a:contains('Click Me')" ).replaceWith($a)
```

Comment: Not seeing any difference.  Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FlAdrU0ZNvaUNmK1S6e6?p=preview.

Comment: If it possible find a element by parant element that contains it. and set html($a). To find it there are many cases. Just see main idea, find it and replace with html you need after load.